# How to fix the custom app bar height wrapped in SliverAppBar Flutter

Tags: flutter

Iam trying to develop app bar when scrolled gets hidden.I have successfully created but appbar is small

The code below provides me appbar like this
[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: NestedScrollView(
     headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    return <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(        
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,   
        title: PreferredSize(
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: CustomAppBar(),
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      ' Bike Guru',
                      style: GoogleFonts.caveatBrush(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + 350)),
        floating: true,
        pinned: false,
      ),


    ];
    },
```

Iam trying to get result which gets hidden when scrolled down
[image]

the custom app bar code

```
class CustomAppBar extends CustomClipper<Path> {
@override
Path getClip(Size size) {
Path path = new Path();

path.lineTo(0, size.height);
path.quadraticBezierTo(
    size.width / 4, size.height - 40, size.width / 2, size.height - 20);

path.quadraticBezierTo(
    3 / 4 * size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height - 20);

path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

return path;
}

@override
bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
return false;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

this is just an overview of your question
you may need `SliverPersistentHeader` widget to fix height and width

```
NestedScrollView(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  controller: this._scrollController1,
  headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    return <Widget>[
       SliverPersistentHeader(
         floating: false,
         pinned: false,
         delegate: SliverAppBarDelegate(
           minHeight: AppConfig.trendHeaderImageHeight,
           maxHeight: AppConfig.trendHeaderImageHeight,
           child: trendingHeader,
         )
       )
    ];
  },
  body: CustomScrollView(
    controller: this._scrollController2
    ...
  ),
);
```